# Python: write df to json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have dataframe

```
month                             2015-05  2015-06  2015-07  2015-08  2015-    09  \
ID                                                                              
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401        0        0        0        1        1   
0011ec51ddb5a41abb2d451fdfa0996a        0        0        0        1        1   
0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136        1        1        1        1        1   
0014ff1f6a95d789d3be3df5249cfe2f        0        0        0        1        1
```

I try to write it to json and get smth like

```
{
  "123": {
    "2015-12-14": 0, 
    "2015-12-15": 1, 
    "2015-12-16": 1, 
    "2015-12-17": 0
  }, 
  "456": {
    "2015-12-14": 0, 
    "2015-12-15": 1, 
    "2015-12-12": 1, 
    "2015-12-13": 1
  }
}
```

But I get

```
{
  "2015-05": {
    "00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401": 0, 
    "0011ec51ddb5a41abb2d451fdfa0996a": 0, 
    "0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136": 1, 
    "0014ff1f6a95d789d3be3df5249cfe2f": 0, 
    "0017fbf132aac12d0f9f3ecb9ee7813d": 0, ...
```

How can I change that and get in first key ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try  `df.to_json(orient="index")`, where `df` is your `DataFrame` object.

For example,

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
            a  b    c
deadbeef  foo  1  2.5
f005ba11  bar  3  4.5
7e1eca57  baz  5  6.5

In [33]: df.to_json(orient="index")
Out[33]: '{"deadbeef":{"a":"foo","b":1,"c":2.5},"f005ba11":{"a":"bar","b":3,"c":4.5},"7e1eca57":{"a":"baz","b":5,"c":6.5}}'
```

Let's jump through some hoops to see a nicely formatted version of that string:

```
In [56]: s = df.to_json(orient="index")

In [57]: print(json.dumps(json.loads(s), indent=4))
{
    "deadbeef": {
        "a": "foo", 
        "c": 2.5, 
        "b": 1
    }, 
    "7e1eca57": {
        "a": "baz", 
        "c": 6.5, 
        "b": 5
    }, 
    "f005ba11": {
        "a": "bar", 
        "c": 4.5, 
        "b": 3
    }
}
```